# Distributed Replay DCOM issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 2 SQL Servers in a Domain. Windows Firewall is disabled on both servers and there is no hardware firewall. Both servers are in the same subnet.

One server, called Controller is configured as a Distributed Replay Controller. The other sever, called Client is configured as a Distributed Replay Client.

The Distributed Replay Controller service is started, but when I try to start the Distributed Replay Client service, I get the following error in the Client Log:

```
[0xC8100005 (6)] Failed to connect controller with error code 0x800706BA.
```

In the Windows System log, I see the following error:

```
DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer controller using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID      830 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\DReplayClient\DReplayClient.exe).
```

The same account is running both services and this is actually a Domain Admin (Yes I know that's bad practise, but its a sandbox environment), and I have checked that the account specifically has the following DCOM permissions set on the Controller:

Local Launch
Local Activation
Remote Launch
Remote Activation
Local Access
Remote Access
and Full Control for configuration

Both servers running Windows Server 2012 Datacentre and SQL 2014 Enterprise

I have even tried giving the Domain's Eveyone group these permissions.

I have even rebuilt the Controller.

The servers can ping each other via both IP Address and Name

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure DCOM permissions as DCOM is used for the RPC communications between controller and clients as well as the controller and administration tool. I think this link might help you (under the heading DCOM permissions). [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878263.aspx)

I won't repeat all the info on here since its on the msdn page but following all the steps on there allowed me to get distributed replay working.